# Ayuda con código PHP

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código tengo problemas el archivo log de apache me da estos errores

```
[Mon Oct 07 23:37:10.350451 2019] [:error] [pid 2391] [client 192.168.1.2:5156] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /var/www/html/index.php on line 37
[Mon Oct 07 23:37:10.350496 2019] [:error] [pid 2391] [client 192.168.1.2:5156] PHP Warning:  mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /var/www/html/index.php on line 39
[Mon Oct 07 23:37:10.350507 2019] [:error] [pid 2391] [client 192.168.1.2:5156] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /var/www/html/index.php on line 48
[Mon Oct 07 23:37:10.350514 2019] [:error] [pid 2391] [client 192.168.1.2:5156] PHP Warning:  mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /var/www/html/index.php on line 50
[Mon Oct 07 23:37:10.350526 2019] [:error] [pid 2391] [client 192.168.1.2:5156] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: mensaje in /var/www/html/index.php on line 162
```

Requiero que alguno de ustedes me pueda ayudar

```
<?php

include("lib.php"); 

if($_SESSION['logueado']){
    if($_SESSION['tipo_acceso'] == 1){ 
        /// administrador
        header("Location: ./fadmin/");
    }elseif($_SESSION['tipo_acceso'] == 2){ 
        /// seccion uploader
        header("Location: ./admincontent/");
    }elseif($_SESSION['tipo_acceso'] == 3){ 
        /// super dealer
        header("Location: ./sdealer/");
    }elseif($_SESSION['tipo_acceso'] == 4){ 
        /// dealer
        header("Location: ./dealer/");
    }elseif($_SESSION['tipo_acceso'] == 5){ 
        /// dealer
        header("Location: ./admin_dealer/");
    }else{
        header("Location: ./nopermitido.php");
    }
}

$fecha = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // fecha en formato timestamp. 
$ip = ipRealCliente();
$q_ip = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM baneos_ip WHERE ip='$ip'"); 

if(mysqli_num_rows($q_ip) >=1) {
    header("Location: ./bloqueado.php?session=".sha1(rand(1243,25488)));
    exit;
}    

$q_msj = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM mensajes_sistema WHERE panel like '%login%'"); 

if(mysqli_num_rows($q_msj) >=1){ 
    $i=1; 
    while ($res = mysqli_fetch_array($q_msj)) {
        # code...
        $mensaje_sistema .= "<h4>".$res['titulo']."</h4> <p>".$res['mensaje']."</p>";
        $i++;
    }

    $mensaje = '<style>
        .alert-warning {
        background-color: #FFE665;
        border-color: #7D5502;
        color: #402903;
        }
        </style>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="alert alert-warning fade in">

        '.$mensaje_sistema.'
        </div>
        </div>
    ';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="author" content="Panel VOD ROKU">
        <title>Panel VOD</title>

        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/form-elements.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">

        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/favicon.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">

    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="top-content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text">
                        <h1><img src="assets/img/logo_panel.png" width="500"></h1>
                        <!-- <div class="description">
                            <p>
                                Panel VOD v1.0 ROKU 
                            </p>
                        </div> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 form-box">
                        <div id="loading"></div>
                        <div class="form-top">
                            <div class="form-top-left">
                                <h3>Login</h3>
                                <p id="error">Ingrese su usuario y contraseña:</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-top-right">
                                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-bottom">
                        <form id="formulario" role="form" action="javascript: login();" method="post" class="login-form">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">Usuario</label>
                                <input type="text" id="user" name="user" placeholder="Usuario..." class="form-username form-control" id="form-username">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="sr-only" for="form-password">Contraseña</label>
                                <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="Contraseña..." class="form-password form-control" id="form-password">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn">Entrar!</button>
                        </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php echo $mensaje; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Javascript -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>

        <!--[if lt IE 10]>
        <script src="assets/js/placeholder.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Te está diciendo que hay unas funciones que requieren dos parámetros pero solo estas pasando uno. Unas son porque no has pasado la conexión (no tienes un mysqli_connection). Otras porque al no usarlo lo que devuelven es un null. Revisa cómo hacer una consulta en php

Comment: Me puede dar un ejemplo de como se hace el codigo de forma correcta soy novato.

Comment: Revisa cómo funciona [`mysqli_query` está bien explicado en el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) y hay ejemplos. En tu código debes obtener la conexión y pasarla como 1er parámetro a `mysqli_query` y en 2º parámetro la consulta. Algo así: `mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT ... FROM ...");` donde  `$mysqli` representaría a la conexión. Revisa el enlace y los ejemplos. Todos los demás errores son consecuencia de ese primer error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysqli_connect() es una función que depende de 2 valores: la conexión a la BD y el código sql que quieres ejecutar.

El primer valor se consigue con la función mysqli_connect(), te dejo enlace a una página que lo explica bien (clic [aqui](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php))

El segundo valor es como has hecho, simplemente meter la sentencia SQL entre comillas dobles.

Al final te tendría que quedar algo tal que así:

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'usuario_mysql', 'contraseña_mysql');

$sql = "select * from edificios";
$result_sql = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
```

Te dejo otro link a la página de mysqli_query(), te vienen unos ejemplos bastante útiles (clic [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php))

Comment: gracias por sus respuestas les comento en lib.pdp tengo el codigo para que conecte a mysql
**
<?php
define('DEBUG', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if (DEBUG)
{ini_set('display_errors', 'On');}
else
{ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');}
ini_set('display_errors',0);
$servidor='localhost';
$usuario='root';
$clave='cars';
$bd='casa';
mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$clave,$bd) or die("Error al conectar con db: ".mysqli_error());
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
session_start();


?>**

Comment: Qué te muestra el mysqli_error() ? @MarcosAmadorBonilla